# CSS hide placeholder on print

Tags: css, printing, placeholder, html-input

Is there a way to hide an input's placeholder text in the print style sheet.  I have a form that can optionally be printed and faxed/mailed. I don't know why someone out want to do that, but that's what the client wants.  So the placeholder text is in the way on the printed document.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Taken from the accepted answer here: [Removing input placeholder on a printable version of an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493360/removing-input-placeholder-on-a-printable-version-of-an-html-page)

You can use a print media query to change the text color transparent. It doesn't "remove" the text, but makes it invisible, so same result...

```
@media print {
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
      color: transparent;
  }
  :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
      color: transparent;
  }
  ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
      color: transparent;
  }
  :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
      color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `text-shadow:none;` if applicable.